# Does Big Deal Alert work if Opportunity buttons are overridden with VF pages

Tags: visualforce, email, opportunity, button, email-alert

I have replaced the New, View, clone and Edit buttons of my Opportunity with VF pages.

I have set the Big Deal Alerts to certain conditions.But receiving empty email body in all mails.

How to display the record details in email body in such scenario..

Any help/Suggestion appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: (1) if in sandbox, have you enabled Email Deliverability = All ? (2) Consult https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activating_big_deal_alerts.htm for tips.

Comment: Hey cropredy,i have it enabled n i am receiving emails..issue is that I am receiving blank emails

Comment: @Laxman, please don't ask the same question twice. Give people a chance to answer your question before posting a similar question phrased differently than this one: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122080/need-to-display-a-vf-page-in-big-deal-alert-email-body

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be NO. The [Big Deal documentation is explicit](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activating_big_deal_alerts.htm&language=en_US):

> The alert message resembles the opportunity detail page including the page layout and language from a selected user.

Why might this be?

- A custom VF page that overrides the Opportunity View page may not render into an email that might be delivered as a plain text email.
- A custom VF page that overrides the Opportunity View page might have user input fields - unrenderable in the email.

You might be better off using Process Builder and email alerts to accomplish the same thing. Big Deal alerts have always struck me as useful to only the most point-and-click-challenged admins.